# Getting two answers using central limit and weak law of large numbers

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_i$ be i.i.d random variables each with mean 1. let $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$. I have to calculate the probability $P(S_n \leq n)$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$. Now using central limit theorem I am getting answer as $\frac{1}{2}$. But by using weak law of large number the solution comes as $1$. I think I am doing some mistake in the second procedure. The steps for the second procedure are as follows :

$$P(S_n \leq n)= P(\frac{S_n}{n} \lt 1+\epsilon)=P(\frac{S_n}{n} -1 \lt \epsilon) \geq P(|\frac{S_n}{n}-1| \lt \epsilon) \geq 1$$ when n goes to infinity. Where am I wrong ?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Sorry I forgot to mention that

Comment: no. for example, the set $\{|x|<2\} \subseteq  \{x<2\}$.

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your first equality, that 
$P(S_n \le n) = P(\frac{S_n}{n} < 1 + \epsilon)$, is incorrect.

For any fixed epsilon, the right-hand side $P(\frac{S_n}{n} < 1 + \epsilon)$ actually is the probability $P(S_n < n + n\epsilon)$ and is not equal to $P(S_n \le n)$, because $n\epsilon \to \infty$ as $n$ goes to infinity, so you're actually looking at the probability that $S_n$ lies in a much larger range $(−\infty, n + n\epsilon)$ rather than the range $(−\infty, n]$ that $P(S_n \le n)$ corresponds to.

---

In fact $P(S_n < n + n\epsilon) = 1$ just as you have proved, and this fact is no surprise in light of the central limit theorem either, because what the central limit theorem says is that $|S_n − n|$ is of the order of $\sqrt{n}$, not $n$. More precisely, we have 
$$P\left(\frac{S_n}{n} < 1 + \epsilon\right) = P(S_n < n + n \epsilon) = P\left(\frac{S_n-n}{\sqrt{n}} < \epsilon\sqrt{n}\right)$$
For any real number $c$ we have $\epsilon\sqrt{n} > c$ for sufficiently large $n$, and therefore (assuming that the $X_i$s have finite variance say $\sigma$, for the CLT to be applicable)
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}P\left(\frac{S_n-n}{\sqrt{n}} < \epsilon\sqrt{n}\right) \ge \lim_{n \to \infty} P\left(\frac{S_n-n}{\sqrt{n}} < c\right) = \Phi(c/\sigma)$$
which can be made arbitrarily close to $1$ by picking sufficiently large $c$.

Comment: It is true that $P(S_n \le n) = P(\frac{S_n}{n} \le 1)$, and the latter event (for fixed $n$) is also the same as the event $\frac{S_n}{n} < 1 + \epsilon$ happening for every $\epsilon$ (the intersection of all these events). So it's ok to fix $n$ and let $\epsilon \to 1$ from the right, but instead if you fix $\epsilon$ and let $n$ go to infinity (as you did), it is a *very* different thing.

Comment: @Shreevastava : thanks for the nice explanation

Comment: @prasenjit: Sure... I also got confused at first. :-) It's a subtle point. If you find the answer satisfactory, you can click on the tick mark to "accept" it, so that this question is no longer in the unanswered questions pile.

Answer (score 0):

> The steps for the second procedure are as follows : $$P(S_n \leq n)= P(\frac{S_n}{n} \lt 1+\epsilon)=P(\frac{S_n}{n} -1 \lt \epsilon) \geq P(|\frac{S_n}{n}-1| \lt \epsilon) \geq 1$$ when n goes to infinity. Where am I wrong ?

At two places: the first = sign is wrong since the events $[S_n\leqslant n]$ and $[S_n/n\lt1+\varepsilon]$ do not coincide in general (should be $\leqslant$ instead) and the last $\geqslant1$ sign is wrong and should be replaced by something like $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\cdots=1$.

A correct proof is as follows. Define some random variable $Z_n$ for each $n\geqslant1$ by the identity $S_n=n+\sigma(X_1)\cdot \sqrt{n}\cdot Z_n$, then the central limit theorem asserts that $Z_n\to Z$ in distribution, where $Z$ is standard normal. In particular, $P[Z_n\leqslant0]\to P[Z\leqslant0]$. Since $P[Z\leqslant0]=\frac12$ and $[Z_n\leqslant0]=[S_n\leqslant n]$, this yields
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}P[S_n\leqslant n]=\tfrac12.
$$